# Is there a single word for "place where I belong" or "eventual destination"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am writing an email to the admissions of a university and am very passionate about their goals and vision. It is a very rigorous and very selective program, and I understand that it may take some time for me to get there. However, I want them to understand that this is my "eventual destination" and I want to get there regardless of the time it may take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [goal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goal):

> - The object toward which an endeavor is directed; an end. (AHD)

or [target](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/target):

> - a fixed goal or objective.

- To be admitted to (your) University is my main goal/target.

Answer (score 1):

If you are *certain* that no matter what happens, you will arrive there, then you could could call it your **destiny**. Be aware, though, that it sounds a bit like a prophecy that cannot be avoided, and requiring no effort on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Were this a job, you would say it was your **vocation**.  "A strong feeling of suitability for a particular career or occupation" ([Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vocation)).

For example, I was employed for more than a decade as a technical writer, but I always knew that I really wanted to work in the arts.  Working in the arts was (and is) my vocation.

In the case of a university course, you could safely say that it was your *vocation to study X*.  It's a slightly metaphorical use, but it conveys the sense you want, and it doesn't sound unusual.